# How to reverse any middle chars in any string randomly and left first and last char the same

Tags: java

I want this sentence to out like . What is wrong here because it give me 
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
package first;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;


public class reverseString2 {

public static void main(String []args){



        String str = "The student so lazy";
        String[] split = str.split(" ");
        String middle = null;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : split) {
            middle = s.substring(1, s.length()-1 );
            s = s.replace(middle,RandomStringUtils.random(5, middle));
            output.append(s + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }



}
```

Comment: i want it to be "The sdetunt so lzay" like that or any randomly mixed not normal reverse

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Find out which line fails, put a breakpoint on that line, and examine the relevant variables. You should be able to understand where the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is coming from.

Comment: I don't think `RandomStringUtils.random(int,String)` does what you think it does. You could just as easily get `"The snnnnnt so lzzy"` with it.

Comment: i debug it and it give me error in RandomStringUtils.random(int,String) , but is there any methods else give me random mix of strings ??

Comment: Thanks every body it worked with me as i forget about middle.lenght() instead of 5 that's why it throws  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy and paste your exact stack trace.

I wrote my own random method, because I don't have the the best setup on this machine, and here's what I got:

```
import java.util.*;
class reverseString2 {

public static void main(String []args){



        String str = "The student so lazy";
        String[] split = str.split(" ");
        String middle = null;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : split) {
            middle = s.substring(1, s.length()-1 );
            s = s.replace(middle,random(5, middle));
            output.append(s + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }

    static String random(int i, String s) {
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(char c : ca) list.add(c);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Character ch : list) sb.append(ch);
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

result:

```
# 1:   hide   clone   input   2 seconds ago
result: success      time: 0.09s    memory: 212416 kB     returned value: 0

input: no
output:
The suntedt so lzay
```

Link http://ideone.com/5flnU

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work for everything except words with less than 3 characters. You can't start after the first character and retrieve the next 0 (or less) characters.

Comment: Agreed, but without a stack, that's the best assumption to be made. There's no problem with the rest of his code.

Comment: It should also 'not work but not fail' for Strings of length 3. The first and last would remain the same, and the middle would be length 1 , negating any randomization done to it.

Comment: i tried it and it just get out normally without any exceptions  , right @glowcoder